# Assign values to dictionary by order they were added

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.4

Pretty much what the title says, I want to create a dictionary with phone numbers as keys and every time a new number is added I want its value to increment by one.

Like this: {'7806969':1 , '78708708' : 2} and etc...

```
nodes=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

customers=open('customers.txt','r')
calls=open('calls.txt.','r')
sorted_no={}
for line in customers:
    rows=line.split(";")
    if rows[0] not in sorted_no:
        sorted_no[rows[0]]=nodes[0]
    else:
        sorted_no[rows[0]]= 
print(sorted_no)
```

That was the code I have so far, I tried creating a list for my problem but that plan quickly fell apart.

Comment: You may think about using `collections.OrderedDict`

Comment: Is there a way to solve this without importing anything?

Comment: dictionaries are unordered .... that is to say there is no order for dictionaries ... but you could use tuples or lists instead ... or just use an `OrderedDict`

Comment: Are you creating all the values at once, as in your example?  Or do you need it to also increment the value if you add a new key later in some different part of the code?

Comment: All I want is the value added and then incremented by one each time if the number still does not exist in the dict. Would you care to show how OrderedDict would work? I went on the Python library but its a but murky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a defaultdict and just sort the output if you actually want it sorted by least to most frequent:

```
sorted_no = defaultdict(int)
for line in customers:
    rows = line.split(";")
    sorted_no[rows[0]] += 1
```

Or just use a Counter dict:

```
from collections import Counter
with open('customers.txt') as customers:
    c = Counter(line.split(";")[0] for line in customers )
    print(c.most_common())
```

To actually just increment the count per element and because you have no duplicates use enumerate :

```
with open('customers.txt') as customers:
    sorted_no = {}
    for ind, line in enumerate(customers,1):
        rows=line.split(";")
        sorted_no[rows[0]] = ind
```

Or as a dict comprehension:

```
with open('customers.txt') as customers:
    sorted_no = {line.split(";")[0]:ind for ind, line in enumerate(customers,1)}
```

If order is important simply use:

```
 from collections import OrderedDict
 sorted_no =  OrderedDict()

 with open('customers.txt') as customers:
     sorted_no = OrderedDict((line.split(";")[0], ind) for ind, line in enumerate(customers,1))
```

`enumerate(customers,1)` gives every index of each line in customers but we pass in 1 as the start index  so we start at `1` instead of `0`.

Comment: you may have been able to read what OP wanted better than me ... so OP doesnt actually want ordered dict? (+1 for decoding the question)

Comment: @JoranBeasley,  their code it seems  is attempting to increment based on some crazy looking list indexing logic. If they actually want sorted they can just sort using dict.get as the key

Comment: This is what it returns to me: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'7804922860': 1, '7801234567': 1, '7803214567': 1, '7809876543': 1, '7801236789': 1, '7808907654': 1, '7808765432': 1, '7807890123': 1, '7804321098': 1}) not exactly what I wanted :/

Comment: @no_sleep, if you have repeated values the value will increment. Add a small sample of your input. what do you expect as output when there are no repeated items?

Comment: No, that's the thing there is no repeated values, its just that every time a new key is added I want the value to go from say one key:1 to key2:2 and so on.

Comment: Umm... what is `OrderedDict(int)` meant to do? :p

Comment: @JonClements, ha,  it started life as a defaultdict  ;)

Comment: Your OrderedDict in the last code block is the reverse mapping of the others :)

Comment: @JonClements, what would I do without you :)  Think the signs are there I have done enough for one day!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you, all you need to do is increase the number you're using as you go:

```
sorted_no = {}
with open("customers.txt") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        number = line.split(";")[0]
        if number not in sorted_no:
            sorted_no[number] = len(sorted_no) + 1
```

This produces something like

```
{'7801234567': 4,
 '7801236789': 6,
 '7803214567': 9,
 '7804321098': 7,
 '7804922860': 3,
 '7807890123': 1,
 '7808765432': 2,
 '7808907654': 5,
 '7809876543': 8}
```

where the first unique phone number seen gets `1`, and the second `2`, etc.

Comment: why not just use enumerate? There are actually no dups.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I hadn't read the comment saying that we knew there were no duplicates.

Comment: What does fp stand for?

Comment: @no_sleep: nothing, really-- (well, "file pointer") but it's just a variable name.  I should probably have called it `in_file` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably one of the shorter ways to do it (thank Jon Clements in comments):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4

from collections import defaultdict
import itertools

sorted_no = defaultdict(itertools.count(1).__next__)
for line in customers:
    rows=line.split(";")
    # no need to put anything,
    # just use the key and it increments automagically.
    sorted_no[rows[0]]
```

`itertools.count(1)` produces a generator, which is equivalent (roughly) to:

```
def lazy():
    counter = 0
    while True:
        counter += 1
        yield counter
```

I left my original answer so people can learn about the default-binding gotcha, or maybe even use it if they want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4

from collections import defaultdict

def lazy_gen(current=[0]):
    current[0] += 1
    return current[0]

sorted_no = defaultdict(lazy_gen)
for line in customers:
    rows=line.split(";")
    # no need to put anything,
    # just use the key and it increments automagically.
    sorted_no[rows[0]]
```

It works because [Python's default assignment happens once](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments), and when you use a mutable object (`list` in this case), you can change the function's return value dynamically.

It's a little wierd though :)

Comment: No need for a function here with (mis)using a default argument, use `sorted_no = defaultdict(itertools.count(1).next)` instead...

Comment: @JonClements thanks, I'm not fluent with `itertools` :)